# CCGLSurfaceView Error

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I'm developing some sample code.
I had some problem using cocos2d.
That is the CCGLSurfaceView problem.

Firstly, I imported cocos2d.jar in my project with fps_images.png file.
And i modify my project for using the cocos2d library.

Here are the code.

```
public class ToadActivity extends Activity {

protected CCGLSurfaceView _glSurfaceView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    _glSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);

    setContentView(_glSurfaceView);
}
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(_glSurfaceView);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDisplayFPS(true);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setAnimationInterval(1.0f / 60.0f);
}
}
```

==>>>        _glSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);

Here, My application found a error. And at the result, it is killed in my android simulator.
What's the problem?

Comment: Can you post the call stack you receive when the error is received? It should be in the LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That library are decreated, not update more. It will be better start using: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/. It use c++, to work on android, use JNI (Native code). Code can be ported to other plataforms, like IOs.

Hope it help!